Computing entropy of inverse gamma distribution
I'm trying to compute the entropy of the inverse gamma distribution and it keeps coming out negative. Obviously this is wrong because entropy is always positive. Wikipedia has this derivation for the entropy of the inverse gamma which as far as I can tell is correct: formula
But when I compute this with larger alpha it is often negative. Also there is a standard JS function for this here which gives examples where the output is negative like this:

@example
var v = entropy( 8.0, 2.0 );
// returns ~-0.922

What am I missing?
